# How to prove a squared plus b squared is less than or equal to 7ab?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers

I'm trying to prove:

$$(a+b)^2 \leq 9ab$$ and don't know how to proceed from the conclusion in the title.

Note that $a$ and $b$ have to be large primes.

In the last line of page 11 of the following paper: 
https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf

What I'm trying to prove above is used. I'm not sure how the equivalence holds.

Comment: The title and the content don't agree.

Comment: They are equivalent

Comment: $$(a+b)^2-kab=0$$ is always the equation of a conic in the $(a,b)$ plane.

Comment: @ajfbiw.s: no, they are not. At most, one conic is inside the other since $(a-b)^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab \geq 0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Does the fact that a and b have to be primes change anything?

Comment: @ajfbiw.s: nothing in your question tells that $a$ and $b$ are integers!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Okay, I edited my question

Comment: [Try to add in more context please](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $b=2$ and $a=3571$, the $500^{\text{th}}$ prime, to see that this is clearly false.

Comment: a and b have to be primes, I forgot to add..

Comment: @ajfbiw.s Nope.

Comment: https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf

Comment: Okay, bottom of page 11

Comment: You see that they are using this result, and I'm not sure how the equivalence holds...

Comment: They used this result in this line:

Comment: @ajfbiw.s You should place such information **in the question BEFORE** you ask, else users will have to consistently change their answers to match the question.

Comment: I see. My bad :P

Comment: @ajfbiw.s where in there do you see a squared term?  That doesn't look at all like the question you asked.

Comment: that (q + p ) is less than or equal to 3 * sqrt(N), right?

Comment: So you square both sides.

Comment: @ajfbiw.s You seem to drop a few things when you say $(q+p)$, which is absolutely wrong.  Just because $x+1>x$ does not allow me to say $x>x$ by dropping the $1$, or worse, $1>x$, which is clearly not true.

Comment: Wait the common terms cancel out. So "that (q + p ) is less than or equal to 3 * sqrt(N)" is the only thing left in that inequality

Comment: @ajfbiw.s If $e=k$, why would they even use $e$ **and** $k$?  Clearly, you should reread the document to see what $e$ and $k$ are.

Comment: Wait, e and k are still there. They appear on both sides of the inequality in question.

Comment: If you compare RHS and LHS, what is it that you need to prove in order to prove that inequality? It is "that (q + p ) is less than or equal to 3 * sqrt(N)"

Comment: @ajfbiw.s No, look at the second most right and the right most parts and divide by $3\sqrt N$ to see that $$k/e<1\implies k<e\implies k\ne e$$

Comment: I'm not claiming k = e. You see: "k(p + q)/e is less than or equal to 3k*sqrt(N) /e", right?

Comment: That is part of the last line of page 11.

Comment: Okay, now, for the quoted line to be true, what has to be true?

Comment: This is the second and third terms in the inequality

Comment: @ajfbiw.s Ok, sure, $(p+q)^2\le9N$ is a true statement, but what are $p,q$?  The inequality does not need to be true for all $p,q$, there were probably some requirements that you missed.  TBH, I'm not here to read entire documents, as the context of the question should be posted in the body of the question.  Please go back and include the necessary information required to answer the question **in the question**.

Comment: P and Q are large prime numbers (1024 bits, say), and N is the product of the two...

Comment: (So none of them can be 2)

Comment: I think this is resolved in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If $b\gt7a\gt0$, then $a^2+b^2-7ab=a^2+b(b-7a)\gt0$, so counterexamples such as $(a,b)=(2,17)$ are easy to find.

Note, thought, that if we require $a$ and $b$ to have the same number of bits, so that $a\lt b\lt 2a$, then

$$(a+b)^2\lt(a+2a)^2=9a^2\lt9ab$$

This might explain the inequality in the linked-to paper.

Comment: How then would you explain the inequality in the last line (page 11)\ of the linked Stanford paper?

Comment: @ajfbiw.s I simply think you don't understand the paper.

Comment: see my new comment under your question :)

Comment: @ajfbiw.s, I've only skimmed the paper you linked to, but it appears that the $p$ and $q$ there have (approximately) the same number of bits, e.g., $p\lt q\lt 2p$.

Comment: Wow - I see! That's makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

The line you are referring to reads $|\hat d-d|\le k(p+q)/e\le 3k\sqrt N/e<3\sqrt N $. I suppose you wonder how one can arrive at the "$\le$" in the middle. Indeed, that inequality is equivalent to $(p+q)^2\le 9pq$. 
With $\alpha:=\frac qp$, the inequality $(p+q)^2\le 9pq$ is equivalent to $(1+\alpha)^2\le 9\alpha$, or approximately $0.146<\alpha < 6.85$, so this is just a consequence of what is said in the introduction: that $p$ and $q$ are "large primes of the same size". 
Incidentally, a good implementation of RSA might well decide to make $\frac qp$ larger than that (and avoid many other pitfalls, such as $\alpha$ having a simple continued fraction)